# Hourly time series forecast

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I'm taking a course on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/python-for-time-series-data-analysis/learn/lecture/13773072#overview) to learn a little bit of Time Series prediction and I'm trying to run this piece of code, with hourly data from one year:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

model = ExponentialSmoothing(train['count'],trend='add',seasonal='add',seasonal_periods=12).fit()
```

But once I run this:

```
predictions = model.forecast(24)
```

I get this error:

> ValueWarning: No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start`.
>     ValueWarning)

Which makes me hard to plot the data for comparison, since the index type mismatches between the test data and prediction.

This is how I create the index:

```
idx = pd.date_range(ts_data.index.min(), ts_data.index.max(), freq='H')
ts_data = ts_data.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
ts_data.sort_index(inplace=True)
ts_data.head(10)

    count
date    
2018-11-19 02:00:00 70.0
2018-11-19 03:00:00 84.0
2018-11-19 04:00:00 98.0
2018-11-19 05:00:00 89.0
2018-11-19 06:00:00 87.0
2018-11-19 07:00:00 76.0
2018-11-19 08:00:00 58.0
2018-11-19 09:00:00 36.0
2018-11-19 10:00:00 38.0
2018-11-19 11:00:00 17.0
```

I wonder why the forecast method doesn't return the proper index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a correct index on a dataframe called *ts_data*, but you are fitting your model on a different dataframe called *train*.

Try looking at the index of the *train* dataframe and see if it is in the right format.